# Swissranger camera - fail to open device through ethernet

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am running on the diamondback on a linux and am having problems when connecting the Swissranger (4k) using swissranger_camera found at http://www.ros.org/wiki/swissranger_camera. I have followed the respective tutorial and have noticed that the udev settings had to be changed for the "usb" method of transmission; is there an equivalent when using the ethernet?

Currently I get an error msg as such

[ INFO] [1308857794.573244971]: Connected to master at [localhost:11311]
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 255 (on)
usb_os_find_busses: Found 007
usb_os_find_busses: Found 006
usb_os_find_busses: Found 005
usb_os_find_busses: Found 004
usb_os_find_busses: Found 003
usb_os_find_busses: Found 002
usb_os_find_busses: Found 001
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 007
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 006
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 005
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 004
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 003
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 002 on 002
skipping descriptor 0xFF
skipping descriptor 0xB
skipped 2 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
skipped 7 class/vendor specific interface descriptors
skipping descriptor 0x25
skipped 1 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
skipped 19 class/vendor specific interface descriptors
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 002
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 001
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 0 (off)
[ERROR] [1308857795.791120355]: Exception thrown while connecting to the camera: [SR::open]: Failed to open device!

What steps should I take to config this to use ethernet?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10380/swissranger-camera---fail-to-open-device-through-ethernet/) by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-24**:
You probably won't need udev rules for ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I run the camera as `roslaunch sr_eth.launch`. Before launching the swissranger_camera node, you should set the ethernet address of the camera by editing this launch file (ether_addr parameter) and any other parameter which best fits your application.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) with karma: 288 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on 2011-07-21**:
thanks.For those who might be struggling, I had to do something like this: telnet default ethernet address 192.168.1.42, set the static address by fw_setenv staticip 192.168.1.33 and change my ipv4 settings to have the same three fields as the new static addr, mask 255,255,255,0; power off/on s4k